# OpenSSH rejects private key passphrase

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openssh

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04. When I try to connect to our server

```
ssh user@server -p 1234 -i ~/path/to/my/private-key
```

it asks me 3 times for the private key's passphrase and finally fails, though I always enter the correct one. When I try it with Putty (converted the OpenSSH key to `.ppk`) it works without any problem. What could be the reason?

Comment: What are the permissions of the key? I doubt that's the issuesince usually you'll get an error from other server, but worth checking.

Comment: They are readable/writable by the user only.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-v` (verbose) option to the ssh command line, it could give you a hint.

Also make sure you *really* have the correct passphrase: try changing it with `ssh-keygen -p`